# Hive regex serde for row with 5000 fields

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

We are given rows like this:

```
aa |-| bb |-| cc |-|
```

and we want to extract the fields separated by |-|. I know one solution would be:

```
CREATE TABLE rating_regex(
field1 string, field2 string, field3 string) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH serdeproperties("input.regex" = "(.+)\\|\\-\\|(.+)\\|\\-\\|(.+)\\|\\-\\|",
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s")
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

But what if instead of three fields we get 5000? how would write the regex pattern without repeating (.+)\|\-\| 5000 times?

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:(?:.+?)\|\-\|(?:\s|$)){3}$
```

Try this.See demo.You can extend it as you want to upto `500`.

https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/20